# postgress laravel не сравнивает значение из 7 нулей

Tags: sql, база-данных, laravel, postgresql

Есть таблица с кодами и операторами сотовой связи, где def - код, а start и end диапазон номеров принадлежащий конкретному оператору и региону. Все поля кроме id - string
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получает все поля по условию кроме первого где start 0000000 а end 0099999

Пример запроса удовлетворяющего первому полю `SELECT * FROM defs WHERE  def = '900' AND start < '0010010' and "end" > '0010010'`

Comment: Непонятна суть проблемы. Создайте fiddle с (тестовыми) данными, и покажите текст запроса, дающего неверные, по вашему мнению, результаты.

Comment: Суть проблемы,  что этот запрос : SELECT * FROM defs WHERE  def = '900' AND start < '0010010' and "end" > '0010010' не находит ничего, хотя должен вернуть первую строку. На втором скрине видно, что подобный запрос который берет следующую строку уже работает (запросы охватывающие последующие строки также работают)

Comment: Попробуйте сделать кастинг на UNSIGNED при запросе ( CAST(`start` AS UNSIGNED) < 10010 and CAST(`end` AS UNSIGNED) > 10010 )